# How is the exact flow of this program with respect to the allocation of Memory?

Tags: java

This question was asked in an interview.
According to me the static variables are initialized first.Then the main is executed which calls constructor of class B, which internally calls constructor of class A (since super class). I want to know when exactly is the memory for instance variables allocated and is the flow of program always from super class to sub class ?

```
Class A(){

    int a = 10;

    static int b = 20;

    //constructor

    A(){}

}

Class B extends A{

    int c = 30;

    static int d = 40;


    B(){}


    public static void main(String args[]){

        B b = new B();

    }

}
```

Comment: Read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html and especially "Providing Constructors for Your Classes" section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the first question: *I want to know when exactly is the memory for instance variables allocated* is actually pretty easy if we look at the de-compiled code. Suppose a much more trivial class:

```
public class Test {

    public Test(){
    }

    int i = 3;
}
```

The decompiled code (`javap -c -p Test.class`) will show something like this:

```
   0: aload_0
   1: invokespecial #10  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4: aload_0
   5: iconst_3
   6: putfield      #12 // Field i:I
   9: return
```

Even if it does not tell you much, the thing to get from here, is that initialization of instance fields are put into the constructor, so this is when it happens.

Things are a bit different when you have a *static field*:

```
  public class Test {

    static int j = 5;

    int i = 3;
  }
```

There will be a *static code block* generated, that will be executed before the constructor:

```
 static {};
   Code:
   0: iconst_5
   1: putstatic     #11  // Field j:I
   4: return
```

The second question: *is the flow of program always from super class to sub class* is pretty easy too, once you understand that the first call inside a constructor is *always* a call to `super` in your example. So `B constructor` actually looks like this:

```
B(){
    super();
    ... rest of code
}
```

So *before* you initialize `B`, you actually call `A constructor`, which in turn will call `Object constructor` (because everyone inherits from `Object`).